# is it possible to install/run several instance of openfire server on hosting with operation linux?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, host

I want to install several openfire server XMPP on one hosting with operation linux.

1.Is it possible?

2.is there any guide for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you have to be sure to configure the ports on at least one of them to something other than the defaults.  You can't share resources (including the db, if you are not using the embedded one).